# is it possible to do web site authentication sans PHP

Tags: javascript, security, jquery

I would really enjoy avoiding the use of PHP for authenticating users on a website I'm developing, and I was wondering if I could use a SQL database, Apache sans PHP, HTML, Javascript/JQuery, and CSS to accomplish this? I know it's a far-fetched idea probably... but I would be happy if I could.

Comment: Why?  Are you just trying to avoid PHP or any programming language on the back end?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to avoid every server-side language (except Apache's config files), or just PHP?

Comment: I would be interested in looking at other server side languages, but PHP is something I do not adore. And this would be a Linux webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a single web development language, there are tons of options.
Ruby, .Net(C#/VB), Java, Python are some common alternatives.

You could work something out with JavaScript, but it would likely be sacrificing quite a bit of functionality/security.

Comment: [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) would be a perfectly suitable server-side JavaScript solution.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Completely dependent on how you write it. Unless you put a reverse proxy in front of it you can run into cross domain request issues.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into Node.js, or possibly a Python based solution and see what I come up with. I'm just experimenting with the idea of avoiding PHP, but I don't like it so far so avoiding it would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Apache does have some modules like mod_auth_mysql that let you do authentication, but it doesn't look like it's been updated in awhile. The login box will be a pop-up box from the browser that requests username and password. You won't be able to put a Username/Password box on your page like other sites do.

If your webserver can't handle the authentication, you need some sort of "glue" that goes between your server and the browser to handle the authentication piece. PHP does a good job of that, but any of the languages Ryathal mentions would work as well.

If you do use javascript, remember that all of the source code used to secure your site is visible to whoever has the knowledge to look at it.

Comment: + they have the ability to change or ignore that javascript.  Unless it is run within node.js, then it doesn't apply

Comment: thanks for these answers. While PHP may do a good job, I'm looking for alternatives at the least. I would strongly like to explore other options, but I will resort to PHP if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use authentication methods built in to `.htaccess` if the right modules are enabled in your Apache installation.

This is only basic http authentication though so you would just get a popup box and you cannot log out unless you close the browser I don't think.

- [Authentication, Authorization and Access Control - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)

You would need to use a command line utility called `htpasswd` to generate the user files.